# How to change provisioning profile in Xcode5 ?? Adding "Development Profile" But Displaying "Distribution Profile"

Tags: ios7, xcode5

in Xcode 5 i am adding development provisioning profile with required certificates . but when i m setting up this Development profile in Xcode  **Code Signing**  section it showing **Ad-Hoc** profile . Whats the matter? in my **Xcode->organizer**.i set up only development profile.*i have tried all possible solution but not able to sort out this.*i have cleaned up and add this profile so many times to sort out this.

Answer (score 2):

**xcode->preferences->accounts->apple ids->view details**